# distinct and sum in single join query

Tags: sql, join, sum, inner-join, distinct

I have the following join query.. I want records to be distinct with c.checkid and also sum of earnings.. how can I perform both in one single query?

```
select c.CheckID,cv.CheckID,Earnings,TaxableEarnings,Amount,EmployeeCode, CheckDate FROM [Customers0].[pay].[CheckVendorCalc] as cv
inner join  [Customers0].[pay].[Checks] as c
on cv.checkid=c.checkid
where
c.CheckDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' and 
c.CustomerID=360 and
c.EmployeeCode='01' and
(cv.TaxableEarnings !=null or cv.TaxableEarnings!=0)
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `GROUP BY`. A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Comment: I HAVE TRIED ..

select  c.CheckID,cv.CheckID,Earnings,TaxableEarnings,Amount,EmployeeCode, CheckDate,SUM(Earnings) as totalearning FROM [Customers0].[pay].[CheckVendorCalc] as cv
inner join  [Customers0].[pay].[Checks] as c
on cv.checkid=c.checkid
where
c.CheckDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' and 
c.CustomerID=360 and
c.EmployeeCode='01' and
(cv.TaxableEarnings !=null or cv.TaxableEarnings!=0)
group by c.CheckID
order by c.CheckID

BUT GOT ERROR

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: cv.TaxableEarnings !=null or cv.TaxableEarnings!=0
This looks weird. Don't you mean
cv.TaxableEarnings is not null and cv.TaxableEarnings!=0
or just
cv.TaxableEarnings!=0
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`. Any non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause must be present in the `GROUP BY` clause. You can find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

**SQL:**

```
select
  c.CheckID,
  SUM(Earnings) as totalearning
FROM
  [Customers0].[pay].[CheckVendorCalc] as cv
  inner join [Customers0].[pay].[Checks] as c on cv.checkid = c.checkid
where
  c.CheckDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01'
  AND '2022-12-31'
  and c.CustomerID = 360
  and c.EmployeeCode = '01'
  and (
    cv.TaxableEarnings != null
    or cv.TaxableEarnings != 0)
group by
  c.CheckID
order by
  c.CheckID
```